# title not displayed when using sigplanconf class

Tags: titles, acm

I'm using `sigplanconf` document class. Title is not displayed even when `\maketitle` is specified

```
\documentclass{sigplanconf}
\begin{document}
\title{foo}
\authorinfo{bar}
\maketitle

hello world
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you link to the `sigplanconf` class?

Comment: http://www.sigplan.org/authorInformation.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the class provided at [sigplan](http://www.sigplan.org/authorinformation.htm) and reducing the template they provide, results in the requirement of defining the `\doi{}` field to get the file compiled showing the title.

The minimal code is then

```
\documentclass{sigplanconf}
\begin{document}
\doi{nnnnnnn.nnnnnnn}
\title{Title Text}
\authorinfo{Name1}
           {Affiliation1}
           {Email1}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right. I figured it out by trail and error.